# "how to print multiple user inputs on one line"

Tags: python

So basically, I want to ask the user to input any amount of sales figures and then print out all of the inputs on one specifc line, how do i do that.

```
def main():   
   num = int((input("Please enter sales figures: ")))

    while (num != -1  ):
     num = int(input("Please enter sales figures: "))

    print("The sales figures entered were:", num)

main()
```

Comment: Put all the numbers in a list, then print the list.

Comment: You need to fix your indentation.

Comment: could you tell me how to, sorry im really new to this

Comment: Create a list called `numbers`, and use `numbers.append(num)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append all the figures in to a list, and print the list, something like this:

```
def main():
    num = int((input("Please enter sales figures: ")))
    list = []
    list.append(num)

    while num != -1:
        num = int(input("Please enter sales figures: "))
        list.append(num)

    print("The sales figures entered were:", end=" ")
    for num in list:
        if num != -1:
            print(num, end=", ")


main()
```

the end="" argument makes, that it prints in the same line.

Comment: Thanks so much, just a view questions so that i can fully understand the code.:

Comment: what exactly does the list.append do that allows me to print all the inputs onto one line

Comment: list.append adds an element to the last position of the list, for instance:

Comment: list = []

list.append(3)
list.append(2)
list.append(1)

print(list)

>>> [3, 2, 1]

Comment: ahh okay. final q could you explain reasoning for the for loop and the "end="

Comment: The for loop iterates trough every single element of the list, and if the element isn't -1, it prints them. The end=" " statement adds strings together, even when they aren't printed in one line. It's like writing >>>print(num1 + "" + num2)